# Comparing the number 10 stored as a varchar to a float 1.1 fails with arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a known issue where users put non numeric values into a `varchar` column (yes I know I can change it to a float but sometimes a non-numeric is correct in this use case). In order to handle this, I have a SQL Server Agent Job that runs nightly and checks if the value in the column can be cast to a float and if not, sets a flag in another column called `INRLevelYN` to 1 telling other queries/views to ignore that row.

Even though casting the value 10 from the `varchar` column to a float works (and doesn't set the `inrlevelyn` flag), when doing a comparison on the column `inrlevel > 1.1` throws an error (*Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric*).

```
select * 
from VM_AntiCoag_Rosendaal_v2 
where dateofdoseinr between '1/26/2017' and '1/26/2017' 
  and inrlevel > 1.1
```

This seems to happen if the value in the `inrlevel` column is 10 or greater. If I change the value to 9.9 or 9, the query returns with no error.

Wrapping the `inrlevel` in a cast as float resolves the issue as well (see below)

```
select * 
from VM_AntiCoag_Rosendaal_v2 
where dateofdoseinr between '1/26/2017' and '1/26/2017' 
  and cast(inrlevel as float) > 1.1
```

I know the cast as float solution works, but I am wondering if this is a known issue or if there are any other suggestions out there. Since I can cast it to float, why doesn't SQL Server handle it properly once it hits the value 10 vs 9.9 or 9.

I have reviewed the suggested questions on stackoverflow and do not feel they answer this particular question although one was close addressing numbers in the three digit range vs two digit range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are implicitly casting inrlevel as `numeric (2,1)` because that is what the scale and precision of **1.1** is. It's the same as writing:

```
select cast(10 as numeric(1,1))
```

Since you must explicitly cast this to avoid it, I'd cast it on your number, not the column, so the function only has to be called once.

```
select 1 where '10' > cast(1.0 as numeric(4,2))
```

Or in your case... just use the proper precision and scale

```
select * 
from VM_AntiCoag_Rosendaal_v2 
where dateofdoseinr between '1/26/2017' and '1/26/2017' 
      and inrlevel  > cast(1.1 as numeric(4,2))
```